# Parametric equation with image of a function.

Tags: parametric

Find all values of $a$ for which the image of the function

$$y=\frac{\sqrt{a}-2\cos x+1}{\sin^2x+a+2\sqrt{a}+1}$$

contains $[2, 3]$.

Now, I've already transformed it to

$$y=\frac{(\sqrt{a}+1)-2\cos x}{(\sqrt{a}+1)^2+1-\cos^2 x}$$

And in turn

$$y=\frac{b-2t}{b^2+1-t^2}, b=\sqrt{a}+1\ge 1, t\in[-1, 1]$$

However it is not clear what I should do next. Is there some elegant solution I am missing?

Comment: contains $[2,3]$ as in??

Comment: The entire interval from 2 to 3 including the ends.

Comment: Hint: Set $2 \leq y \leq 3$ then solve for $a$.  I highly suggest setting $y = 2$, then try solving for $a$ to see what you're up to.

Answer (score 0):

The latter function is continuous on the interval. So that's enough to find all $b$'s such that $y$ take both of the values $2,3$. Now if $y$ take this two values, then takes all the values $[2,3]$ by the mean value theorem.